# Update a set of Columns with criteria based on another table?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I've two tables :

> table_1 - ControlID, Code,
> ReportedDate, FiledDate Age,
> AgeCategory, etc.,
>
> table_2 - ControlID, Code,
> ReportedDate, FiledDate etc.,

`ControlID` in `table_1` is **Foreign key** whereas **not in table_2**. I need to update ReportedDate in table_1 with ReportedDate in table_2 and Age and AgeCatogory has been calculated and fine.

I want to update those three columns in table_1, where ControlID, FiledDate and Code in both are identical.

Now far I've :

```
UPDATE table_1 SET ReportedDate=table_2.ReportedDate, Age='<value>' AgeCategory='<value>'
         WHERE table_1.ControlID=table_2.ControlID AND
         table_1.FiledDate=table_2.FiledDate AND table_1.Code=table_2.Code
```

If anyone has the idea of how could it be resolved???

Anyhelp would be appreciated...

**EDIT:**

I'm getting error saying MySQL Syntax error at `'FROM ...'`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the wrong data updated? Is there an error in your SQL? Please be more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UPDATE table_1
    JOIN table_2 
    ON table_1.ControlID=table_2.ControlID
         AND table_1.FiledDate=table_2.FiledDate
         AND table_1.Code=table_2.Code
    SET table_1.ReportedDate=table_2.ReportedDate, 
         table_1.Age='<value>',
         table_1.AgeCategory='<value>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no FROM allowed within the UPDATE syntax [1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] tbl_name
    SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

If you like to fetch content from a second table, you might want to use a subquery.

Try this code:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET ReportedDate=
    (SELECT ReportedDate FROM table_2
      WHERE table_1.ControlID = table_2.ControlID
      AND table_1.Code = table_2.Code
    ), Age='<value>' AgeCategory='<value>'
```

Comment: Thanx, I've found like this for the same sort of problem in our 'SO'. I've modified the query. The same error occurs. Can U help me fix it? Can U spot which way I should modify it?

Comment: I just added some code. I'm not sure, weather it works, but this is what I might try.